# Static compilation error with gcc

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile the following code :

```
#include<stdio.h>

void func()
{
    printf("In function\n");
    return ;
}

int main()
{
    printf("In mains\n");
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

using `gcc -static -o try try.c` but getting the following error :

```
/usr/bin/ld: error: hidden symbol '__ehdr_start' is not defined locally
/usr/bin/ld: error: hidden symbol '__ehdr_start' is not defined locally
/usr/bin/ld: error: hidden symbol '__ehdr_start' is not defined locally
/usr/bin/ld: error: hidden symbol '__ehdr_start' is not defined locally
/usr/bin/ld: error: hidden symbol '__ehdr_start' is not defined locally
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

am i doing anything wrong ?

Gcc version i have is `gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5)`

Comment: compiles and runs fine. Have you tried googling `error: hidden symbol '__ehdr_start'` It looks like you have stray garbage in your file. What OS are you running and what editor are you using? Your not editing in MS-Word or some nonsense like that are you?

Comment: Take a look at [**Binutils Released**](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2014-01/msg00286.html). It has some information to check. Compare the versions of the apps you have to the ones discussed.

Comment: I googled it , its related to some patch in gcc or ld. I am not able to understand the whole patch thing so i asked here. I am using kali linux [ Debian fork ] . Editor is vim.

Comment: It looks like if you have `binutils 2.24.51.0.2` or earlier, you may need to update to get a fix that was applied.

Comment: kali repo doesn't have updated version. do anybody know where to download the latest one ?

Comment: Specifically, it looks like Update from binutils 2012 0806 added support of __ehdr_start symbol for the ELF file header. Then in update for 2.24.51 a bug was fixed related to it. I have 2.23.2 and I do not see any problems and I have 2.24 on another box and don't see problems there.

Comment: How to check the binutils version ? on doing binutils -v i am getting GNU Binutils for Debian 2.22 .

Comment: DONE!!!! Its was a problem of version.

Comment: Ok, that sounds fair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [**Binutils Released**](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2014-01/msg00286.html). It looks like if you have `binutils 2.24.51.0.2` or earlier, you may need to update to avoid a bug with `__ehdr_start` symbol. Specifically, it looks like Update from binutils 2012 0806 added support of __ehdr_start symbol for the ELF file header. Then **in update for 2.24.51 a bug was fixed related to __ehdr_start**.

I have version 2.23.2 on openSuSE and I do not see any problems and I have 2.24 on an Archlinux box and don't see problems there. So the problem seems version specific related to versions between binutils 2012 0806 release and 2.24.51.

Glad you got it solved.